# Meaning of Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

Tags: excel, vba

I have come accross a piece of code which contains 
Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)
I am not able to understand the syntax .Range("B" & rnum)

rnum is a variable used as a counter in the code.

Can anyone throw some light and explain what this line in the code means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*BaseWks* probably refers to a worksheet object.
*BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)* is referring to a single cell on that worksheet.

So, assuming *rnum* increases with every step with 1, and assuming the loop starts at *rnum=1*, then in the first step of the loop,

```
destrange = BaseWks.Range("B1")
```

and in the second step of the loop,

```
destrange = BaseWks.Range("B2")
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

`destrange` here is a range object

`BaseWks` is the worksheet object

and

`Range("B" & rnum)` is some cell in Col B in `BaseWks`

The range object can be written in many ways. For example, Let's take the case of cell A1 in say Sheet1. It can be written in many ways.

**Way 1**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

**Way 2**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    i = 1

    Set rng = ws.Range("A" & i)
End Sub
```

This method is usually used when you are not certain of the row number or when you are looping in a range.

**Way 3**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    i = 1

    Set rng = ws.Cells(i, 1)
End Sub
```

The syntax of `.Cells` in the above case is `.Cells(Row, Column)`